# How to unlink contacts?

Tags: contacts

I had a call from a new number. I went to create a new contact for it but accidentally clicked on the first item in my contact list. Now, it doesn't seem possible to unlink or unjoin them. When I view that contact, I can view the 'Joined Contacts', and it is joined to the Google contact I clicked on, and there is a minus icon but it is greyed out. How can I unjoin or unlink them or move this number to a new contact?

Using Samsung Galaxy S on Froyo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't actually a linked contact unless the contact you added it to is from a social network. That's why the unlinking won't work.

Go to edit the number, select the entire number and copy it, then delete it from the wrong contact, go back, add a new contact, long-press the phone no. field and select paste. Or you can use pen and paper too if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

I was searching this question because I had a linked device contact with a google contact. I don't know how I got it that way. To unlink 1 contact from another open the contact. Choose the menu and choose separate contact. From that screen it isn't obvious but there is a faded button on the right of each of the contacts that are linked. When you press it, the device will prompt "Separate contact" Cancel or OK. For me I have a contact that is Exchange and Google. It was also linked to another Google and a Device contact. I had to separate the device contact (another person) and the Google contact (a different other person).

Answer (score 0):

To unlink 1 contact from another open the contact. Choose the menu and choose separate contact. From that screen you will see a ( - ) button on the right of each of the contacts that are linked. When you press it, the device will prompt "Separate contact" tap  ( OK ). Do this to each of the contacts you want to unlink, the last one will stay because its the one that the link was created with.